# Can you export the entire spatial map from hololens?

Tags: hololens

Is there a way to export the entire scanned environment from a Hololens 2? Using the device portal, I can either export the closest 128 blocks as .obj, or what I assume is the entire dataset in .mapx format. I'd like to either export more than 128 blocks, export in sections but with a consistent alignment so I can stitch them together, or convert the .mapx to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended you using Scene understanding SDK to query a static version of the spatial mapping data and save a serialized scene bytes to disk.
After scanning the room, invoke [`SceneObserver.ComputeSerializedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/scene-understanding-sdk#initialization-from-data-aka-the-pc-path) to serialize the scene as a byte array.

[Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples) is a Unity-based sample application that showcases Scene Understanding on HoloLens 2. And it shows up how to save any scene you've captured by saving the output of ComputeSerializedAsync to file: [Line1154](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples/blob/master/Assets/SceneUnderstanding/Core/Understanding/Scripts/SceneUnderstandingManager.cs#L1154)

Besides, the `SaveObjsToDiskAsync` function show how to save the Unity Objects from Scene Understanding as Obj files: [Line1206](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples/blob/master/Assets/SceneUnderstanding/Core/Understanding/Scripts/SceneUnderstandingManager.cs#L1206)